# c# email object to stream to attachment

Tags: c#, email, filestream, attachment

I'm trying to create and send an email attachment from an object which is a list of lists.  I found a nicely documented answer [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527214/how-do-i-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-system-net-mail) but still have some confusion.

It mentions "get some binary data"

```
//Get some binary data
byte[] data = GetData();
```

I have tested my data by:

```
Console.WriteLine(ieLog.FirstName + "." + ieLog.LastName);
```

I guess my question is how do I turn that into a stream if it isn't already one and then use:

```
//save the data to a memory stream
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
```

and then send the attachment?

Thank you for any help or hints.

I would like to be an excel doc or csv if I can't figure that out.  I'm sure there are already classes for this sort of thing, where does a newb look for that sort of information?

Comment: what is ieLog? A class of your own?... how do you expect that to be attached to the email, as a binary file?

Comment: What is it, if it is not a stream (or `byte[]`)?

Comment: ieLog is a basic list of login logout times.  I would like to attach it as an Excel doc or csv.  I'm not stuck on the stream method, it is just all I have found so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote it directly in the browser, but it should be ok:

```
...

byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(ieLog.FirstName + "." + ieLog.LastName);

using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "myFile.csv", "text/csv" ));

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
    smtp.Send(mail);   
}
```

Comment: You should be disposing of mail (which I'm guessing is a Message) and also in .Net 4 onwards dispose of smtp.