# C# Attaching System.Drawing.Image to Email

Tags: c#, image, email, email-attachments, memorystream

Is there any way to attach System.Drawing.Image to email with out saving it, then grabbing it from the saved path.

Right now I'm creating the image and saving it. I then send email with:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                string _body = "body"

                mail.Body = _body;
                string _attacmentPath;
                if (iP.Contains(":"))
                    _attacmentPath = (@"path1");//, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
                else
                    _attacmentPath = @"path2");
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_attacmentPath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
                mail.To.Add(_imageInfo.VendorEmail);
                mail.Subject = "Rouses' PO # " + _imageInfo.PONumber.Trim();
                mail.From = _imageInfo.VendorNum == 691 ? new MailAddress("email", "") : new MailAddress("email", "");
                SmtpClient server = null;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal; 
                server = new SmtpClient("server");
                try
                {

                    server.Send(mail);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
```

Is there anyway to directly pass the System.Drawing.Image to mail.Attachments.Add()?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't pass an `Image` directly to an attachment, but you can skip the file system by just saving the image to a `MemoryStream`, and then providing that `MemoryStream` to the attachment constructor:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
stream.Position = 0;

mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "image/jpg"));
```

Comment: +1 - Your code is more compact and clean than the one I used. =)

Comment: thanks, this worked, just took me a couple of trys to realize i had to add ".jpg" to the end of the name parameter!

Answer (score 5):

In theory, you can convert the Image to a MemoryStream, and then add the stream as an attachment. It would go like this:

```
public static Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat formaw) {
  var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  image.Save(stream, formaw);
  stream.Position = 0;
  return stream;
}
```

Then you can use the following

```
var stream = myImage.ToStream(ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Now that you have the stream, you can add it as an attachment:

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "myImage.gif", "image/gif" ));
```

References:

[System.Drawing.Image to stream C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp)

[c# email object to stream to attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604726/c-sharp-email-object-to-stream-to-attachment)