# ReadTimeout and writeTimeout Exception thrown when attaching a file to calendar event programatically

Tags: c#, outlook, mailing

When I am trying to attach file in My Calendar event through C# code for Outlook I am getting this error and mail is getting triggered but without the attachment.

My Code as Bellow

```
private static MailMessage MailMessageComp(DateTime dtStartDateTime, DateTime dtEndDateTime, string sSubject,
        string sSummary, string sLocation, string sOrganizerName, string sOrganizerEmail, MailAddressCollection attendeeList, DataMailItem _mailItem, bool bStatus) {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType textType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/plain");
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType HTMLType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType calendarType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");

        calendarType.Parameters.Add("method", ((bStatus) ? "CANCEL" : "REQUEST")); // "REQUEST");
        calendarType.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");

        AlternateView textView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_mailItem.Body, textType);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(textView);

        AlternateView HTMLView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_mailItem.Body, HTMLType);
        string attachmentName = "myPdf.pdf";
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(HTMLView);
        //create the Body in VCALENDAR format
        string calDateFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
        string bodyCalendar = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n" + "METHOD:" + ((bStatus) ? "CANCEL" : "REQUEST") + "\r\n" + "PRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange\r\n" + "VERSION:2.0\r\n" 
            + "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n" + "TZID:(GMT-06.00) Central Time (US & Canada)\r\n" + "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-TZID:11\r\n" + "BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n" + "DTSTART:16010101T020000\r\n"
            + "TZOFFSETFROM:-0500\r\n" + "TZOFFSETTO:-0600\r\n" + "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU\r\n" + "END:STANDARD\r\n" + "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\n" 
            + "DTSTART:16010101T020000\r\n" + "TZOFFSETFROM:-0600\r\n" + "TZOFFSETTO:-0500\r\n" + "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU\r\n" 
            + "END:DAYLIGHT\r\n" + "END:VTIMEZONE\r\n" + "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTAMP:{8}\r\n"
            + "ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=" + "TestFile.pdf" + ":{10}\r\n"
            + "DTSTART:{0}\r\n" + "SUMMARY:{7}\r\nUID:{5}\r\n" +
            "{9}\":MAILTO:{9}\r\nACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{4}\":MAILTO:{4}\r\nORGANIZER;CN=\"{3}\":mailto:{4}\r\nLOCATION:{2}\r\nDTEND:{1}\r\nDESCRIPTION:{7}\\N\r\nSEQUENCE:1\r\nPRIORITY:5\r\nCLASS:\r\nCREATED:{8}\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:{8}\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ATTENDEE-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNER-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nACTION:DISPLAY\r\nDESCRIPTION:REMINDER\r\nTRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";

        bodyCalendar = string.Format(bodyCalendar,
            dtStartDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString(calDateFormat),
            dtEndDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString(calDateFormat),
            sLocation,
            sOrganizerName,
            sOrganizerEmail,
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"),
            sSummary,
            ((bStatus) ? "Cancelled " : "")+ sSubject,
            DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(calDateFormat), BuildAttendees(attendeeList, ((bStatus) ? "CANCEL" : "NEEDS-ACTION"))
            , GetRDocPDFAttachment(_mailItem.ProjectRefNo.ToString(), _mailItem.ResponseId.ToString()));
        //attendeeList.ToString());
        AlternateView calendarView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyCalendar, calendarType);
        //calendarView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(calendarView);

        //  Adress the message
        msg.From = new MailAddress(sOrganizerEmail, sOrganizerName);
        foreach(MailAddress attendee in attendeeList) {
            msg.To.Add(attendee);
        }
        msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(_mailItem.From.EmailAddress, _mailItem.From.Name));
        msg.Subject = sSubject + ((bStatus) ? " - Cancelled" : "");
        return msg;
    }
```

This MailMessage is getting composed and then I am mailing it.

Everything is fine except the attachment to calendar event.

Please help.

Thanking you in advance.
Umakanta(Babu).

Answer (score -1):

In this code, you are not actually attaching a file, but are creating a message with text, HTML, and calendar alternate views.  However, nowhere do you attach a file to the MailMessage.

You have declared a string holding an attachment name:

```
string attachmentName = "myPdf.pdf";
```

However, this attachmentName is never referenced again.  If you mean to add this to the message, you must do so with:

```
msg.Attachments.Add(...)
```

You can see [How do I add an attachment to an email using System.Net.Mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527214/how-do-i-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-system-net-mail) for more details on how to actually add the attachment.

I hope I have understood the question correctly, and  I hope this helps.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned attachment to the Calendar Event not to the mailmessage attachment. So My string composition contains the attachment procedure to attach which Like ATTACH: xxxxxxxxxxxx in the calendar string building with Base64 Conversion of the Attachment file. Please go through the question properly.

Comment: Well, your question is not the clearest one I have ever seen.  At first, I thought maybe you meant attachment to the Calendar Event, but I could not see anything wrong with the code there, so I re-read the question and then thought "aha!", you were trying to attach the pdf file, as I did see something wrong there.  I even built a test app to try this, so I am disappointed at the downvote as I put in some effort to understand this.  Well, with downvoting people who are sincerely trying to help you, good luck getting this answered.